# How to make ASP.Net Web API Token still valid for multiple application server when using loadbalancer?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-web-api, load-balancing

Currently I am developing REST web service using ASP.Net Web API, I only customizing out of the box OAuth Provider from Katana Stack. The requirement of this project also the system must have ability handle any request when load balancer applied in this system architecture. 
So back to my question, how to make ASP.Net Web API Token still valid for multiple application server when using loadbalancer?

Thanks

Comment: Which ASP.Net Web API Token are you talking about ?

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from the question, if you're going to act as identity provider or consume 3pty identity provider service... - I'm assuming you'll be IdP and you'll need somehow to treat authenticated user in the same way across your cluster. This is common problem of "shared session state" between various servers behind load balancer.

There are two ways:

- invest into some enterprise solution (like ScaleOut state server) and hook you app too it
- write your own

If you decide to write your own poor man "shared session state" there are couple of ways around.

1) Database table - make some DB table with parameters [Key], [Value], [Date], (in your case probably key will be the OAuth Token, Value will be state for such user, [Date] is date when token was created; every time you touch the state you have to update the [Value] by [Key]; also implement some sort of purging based on [Date]

2) Web service - deploy (on single box) service that will act as "shared session provider" - essentially the same as with database table, only the values are being stored into HttpCache instead of db table

3) Everything on the client - provided your "shared state" is not too long (personal recommendation 4KB max) you can use cookies to store values directly on client

Comment: Thank for your answer, actually I was implement point 1 and 2 that you mention above, but its not the solution for my unclear question above hehehe. But today I have solve my problem, the solution is I must implement Microsoft.Owin.Security.DataProtection.IDataProtector as access token format. AccessTokenFormat = new TicketDataFormat(new ApiTokenProtector())